# How does the glVertexAttribPointer stride parameter work?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glew

How does the `stride` parameter of the `glVertexAttribPointer` function work?
Lets say I have a buffer which is 64 bytes large. I want to store 2 vertices which are 32 bytes large each. If the vertices start one after another, does the stride parameter need to be 0 or 32? What I'm trying to say is does the stride parameter count from the start of the last vertex or from the end of the last vertex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It counts from the start of the previous vertex.

But `stride == 0` is a special case, it means that your attributes are tightly packed. So e.g. if you're passing a `dvec4` (vector of 4 doubles) per vertex, it doesn't matter if you use `0` or `32` (if `sizeof(double) * 4 == 32`).

Comment: thanks. I was confused because I watched a youtube video that said one thing and I read documentation that said another.

Comment: in other words: you should use the actual stride, *or* use 0 as a special shortcut which means no gaps (stride = size)

Comment: Thanks, your answer cleared my confusion